# Allowing line breaks in comments Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Any ideas to prevent Wordpress stripping new lines from comments?

Comment: Can you give more information, please: is this on a stock, or a downloaded, template - or are you building your own? Have you checked the source of the outputted page to see if there are newlines present? (That is, is the template not adding the necessary HTML to the output?)

Comment: Im using the included Kubrick template. In the source all html tags are stripped.

Comment: Are there newlines in the output comments, though? And what HTML tags have been stripped that you included in the new comments?

Comment: No new lines in the source, its all concated on one line. I did try <p> <br /> <br> and <b>

Answer (score 0):

I believe this plugin supports line breaks in comments, along with a host of other formatting options:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymcecomments/